# How to set the width of material ui Popper to its container's width while setting disable portal as false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using [material-ui popper](https://material-ui.com/components/popper/).

I want to let the popper go put of container in y-direction. So I set `disableportal={false}`.

But after setting `disableportal` to false, when I give `width: 100%`, popper is occupying the entire browser's width instead of just it's container's width. I don't want the popper to go out of container in x direction but adjust it's width to the width of it's container.
How do I achieve this? Please check below code for reproducing the above issue.

```
import ClickAwayListener from '@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener';
import Grow from '@material-ui/core/Grow';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import MenuList from '@material-ui/core/MenuList';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Popper from '@material-ui/core/Popper';
import React from 'react';

const items = [
  'fsdfsdfsdfs',
  'shosjsadsd',
  'dsfdjhfdksfhdsf',
  'fsdfhdhhhhhhhhh',
];

export function Test() {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

    const handleChange = (event: any) => {
        setValue(event.target.value);
    };

    const renderChildren = () => {
        let renderItems = items;
        if (value !== '') {
          renderItems = items.filter((item: any) => item.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
        }
        return renderItems.map((item: any) => {
            return (
                <MenuItem key={item}>
                    {item}
                </MenuItem>
            );
        });
    };

    const onFoucs = (event: any) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    const popperTrans = ({ TransitionProps }: any) => {
        return (
          <Grow
            {...TransitionProps}
            style={{ transformOrigin: '0 0 0' }}
          >
            <Paper>
                <MenuList>
                    {renderChildren()}
                </MenuList>
            </Paper>
          </Grow>
        );
    };

    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    return (
      <div style={{width: 1000, height: 500}}>
        <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
            <div>
                <Input
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onFocus={onFoucs}
                    value={value}
                    placeholder='Search'
                    style={{width: '100%'}}
                />
                <Popper
                    open={open}
                    anchorEl={anchorEl}
                    transition={true}
                    placement='bottom-start'
                    style={{zIndex: 10000, width: '100%'}}
                >
                    {popperTrans}
                </Popper>
            </div>
        </ClickAwayListener>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this back then? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use `anchorEl?.clientWidth`:

```js
<Popper
  open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  style={{width: anchorEl?.clientWidth}}
>
  {...children}
</Popper>
```

Comment: This solution worked like a charm. I just need to add the .current property:
`style={{ width: anchorRef?.current?.clientWidth }}`

Should be accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: Well, ideally it should be `sx={{width: anchorRef.current?.clientWidth ?? 150}}`

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there must be a better way to do this, but since I couldn't find one...

here is my workaround:

```
const [width, setWidth] = React.useState(DEFAULT_WIDTH);

useEffect(() => {
   setWidth(document.getElementById('container')?.offsetWidth);
}, [document.getElementById('container')?.offsetWidth])

<Button id="container">{text}</Button>
<Popper
    open={open}
    placement="bottom"
    style={{ zIndex: 1, width: `${width}px` }}
>
    {...children}
</Popper>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what is causing the issue for you. I can only point you to the example in the [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#menulist-composition). I inspired my implementation from there and it worked like a charm. One difference that I see from your code sample is that the `<ClickAwayListener>` should be only wrapped around the `<MenuList>`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The answer comes a bit late but I didn't like the other answers and this may help someone:

Here is how to solve the issue with the useRef hook.

I believe you can do the same with your AnchorEl.

```js
import {useState, useRef, ReactNode} from 'react';
import ArrowDropDownIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowDropDown';
import {
  Button,
  ButtonGroup,
  ButtonGroupProps,
  ClickAwayListener,
  Grow,
  MenuItem,
  MenuList,
  Paper,
  Popper,
} from '@mui/material';

interface Props extends ButtonGroupProps {
  primaryButton: ReactNode;
  secondaryButtons: Array<ReactNode>;
}

const SecondaryActionsButton = ({primaryButton, secondaryButtons, ...buttonGroupProps}: Props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const anchorRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setOpen(prevOpen => !prevOpen);
  };

  const handleClose = (event: Event) => {
    if (
      anchorRef.current &&
      anchorRef.current.contains(event.target as HTMLElement)
    ) {
      return;
    }

    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ButtonGroup ref={anchorRef} {...buttonGroupProps}>
        {primaryButton}
        <Button
          size="small"
          sx={{
            borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
            borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
            borderLeft: 0,
          }}
          onClick={handleToggle}
        >
          <ArrowDropDownIcon />
        </Button>
      </ButtonGroup>
      <Popper
        sx={{
          zIndex: 1,
        }}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorRef.current}
        placement="bottom-end"
        transition
        disablePortal
      >
        {({TransitionProps}) => (
          <Grow {...TransitionProps}>
            <Paper
              sx={{
                zIndex: 1,
                borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
                borderTopRightRadius: 0,
                width: anchorRef.current?.clientWidth,
                maxWidth: anchorRef.current?.clientWidth,
                overflow: 'hidden',
              }}
            >
              <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
                <MenuList id="split-button-menu" autoFocusItem>
                  {secondaryButtons}
                </MenuList>
              </ClickAwayListener>
            </Paper>
          </Grow>
        )}
      </Popper>
    </>
  );
};

export default SecondaryActionsButton;
```

Comment: You may have to change the sx props to fit with your how design system and also preferably use MenuItem to wrap secondaryButtons, which is not documented in the code above.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using popper.js that allows you to **override middlewares setting**, you could do this:

Reference: [Match reference width](https://github.com/floating-ui/floating-ui/blob/7ce4aa67b57384c846c0ef806f943c2e0b471240/website/pages/docs/size.mdx#match-reference-width)

> A common feature of select dropdowns is that the dropdown matches the width of the reference regardless of its contents. You can also use size(){:js} for this, as the Rect{:.class}s get passed in:

```
// size fn is the part that does the trick
// you should alter other code to fit your usage scenario
popperProps={{
  middlewares: (presetMiddlewares) => {
    return [
      ...presetMiddlewares,
      size({
        apply({ rects, elements }) {
          Object.assign(elements.floating.style, {
            width: `${rects.reference.width}px`,
          });
        },
      }),
    ];
  }
}}
```